# how to create multiple instances of emgucv.videoCapture() Simultaneous in c#

Tags: c#, wpf, multithreading, emgucv

I use the Emgu CV library to access the IP camera via the RTSP protocol.

To do this, I use the following code.

```
Emgu.CV.VideoCapture (url);
```

The problem arises when I want to connect to multiple cameras at the same time.

When I execute the above code, the connection with the camera is established as follows:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/hnd2L.png

This problem occurs because Emgu CV is used as a wrap in C #. As a global variable.

What needs to happen is that the instances are created simultaneously and separately, as follows:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/FbMD0.png

I used multi-threaded processing but the problem was not solved. Does anyone have a solution?

```
Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
                        {
                            try
                            {
                                var newCamera = new Emgu.CV.VideoCapture(url);
                            }
                            catch (Exception ex)
                            {
                            }
                        });
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try to open the Cameras via the RTSP-Protocol directly. Just check which SDK is available for your camera and connect via those directly.

OpenCV works fine for prototyping but for professional product integration, it is better to move to the software stack of the vendor.